# CGridView and Related Table

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to list with `CGridView` posts of a specified user, but is giving error. What is the correct method of doing this?

Controller.php

```
public function actionListPosts($id)
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->with=array('posts');
    $criteria->condition='t.id=:user_id';
    $criteria->params=array(':user_id'=>$id);

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Users', array(
            'criteria' => $criteria
    ));

    $this->render('list',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

View.php:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView',array(
    'id'=>'events-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider->posts,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'name',
    ),
)); ?>
```

Error:

```
 Property "CActiveDataProvider.posts" is not defined.
```

Comment: You must use the dataProvider with the post model, not with user model

Comment: @dInGd0nG I cannot use relation like that?

Comment: Should I `dataProvider` with `Post` model and add `$criteria->condition='t.user_id=$id'` ? This is the correct method?

Comment: Yes. You can shorten your condition by doing the following: `$criteria->compare('t.user_id', $id);`. That notation will automatically use parameter binding, saving you a step.

Comment: @dInGd0nG You should add an answer so that Luciana can accept it and this question can be closed.

Comment: @LucianoNascimento answer added. close this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the dataprovider for `Post` model instead of `User` model

in controller

```
public function actionListPosts($id)
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->condition='t.user_id=:user_id';
    $criteria->params=array(':user_id'=>$id);

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post', array(
            'criteria' => $criteria
    ));

    $this->render('list',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

and in view

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView',array(
    'id'=>'events-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'name',
    ),
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you also want to be able to search and sort by this column, try out http://www.mrsoundless.com/php/yii/searching-and-sorting-a-column-from-a-related-table-in-a-cgridview/

Answer (score 0):

in controller action you can write---

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('NameofPostTableAR',array(
    'criteria'=>array(
    'condition'=>'post_id='.$id,)));

 $this->render('list',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
));
```

and in view you can write---

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'post-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$dataprovider,
'columns'=>array(
    'post_id',
    'post_name',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
)); ?>
```

Here I hv assumed the field in ur Posts table to be (post_id, post_name)

I hope it wrks in ur case..